# OSX AppleScript fails to run as service

Tags: macos, services, applescript

I would like to run a simple shell command via hotkeys. So far I've created a service via Automator wich runs the following AppleScript command:

```
do shell script "/bin/bash -c '/opt/local/bin/cmus-remote -n'"
```

and does not take any input.

It runs fine when executed from within Automator and also when called from the command line itself, but when I try to execute it as a service -- either via hotkeys or from e.g. Firefox's global menu Firefox->Services --, it fails with an unspecific error.

What do I do wrong?

Thanks in advance!

PS: Hotkey execution works fine if I use [Spark](http://www.shadowlab.org/softwares/spark.php), but I'd still like to know where I went wrong.

Comment: Why don't you `Run Shell Script` with `/bin/bash -c '/opt/local/bin/cmus-remote -n'` instead of `Run Applescript` with `do shell script...`?

Comment: I did that too... same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested with an example script and work for me when I tell the service is available in Firefox. I used this fake script to test:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1 > testfile.txt
```

What I did is the following:

- Save this automator service on `~/Library/Services`. I called it `Service Test`.

[image]

- Then on System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts → Services assign a shortcut to the service.

[image]

- Open Firefox and works both if I execute it from Services menu and using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>.

> $ cat testfile.txt

```
parameter
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: It did indeed... This worked for me as well. It seems that in this case, the issue lies with the specific shell command (maybe because the cmus-remote commands listen to a UNIX socket which cannot be addressed by Apple services?)